# php substring regex

Tags: php, regex, arrays, substr

I've been reading php code all day and what I can't seem to find an answer to what I believe is a simple question.

I've got an array full of strings and I want to see if the first character in a string is a number, then do something with it, e.g:

```
if substr($stringArray[$i],0,1) == regexsomething[0-9]) { do stuff }
```

Have I got this all wrong?

Surely I could set the regex to be [^0-9] to match at the start but the PHP preg_match is confusing me greatly.

Any advice would be super.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside brackets, `^` means "start", but right after a `[`, it means "invert this whole class". `/[^0-9]/` would match anything that contains a non-digit. A regular expression to match a single digit would be:

```
/^[0-9]$/
```

PHP already has a function for this, though: [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric)

```
if ( is_numeric( substr( $stringArray[$i],0,1 ) ) ) { do stuff }
```

If you want to go the regex route, you won't need to get the first character. A regex that matches anything that starts with a digit would be:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^[0-9]/', $stringArray[$i] ) ) { do stuff }
```

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, typo on the position of the ^.  Thanks Tim!

Comment: `is_numeric( $stringArray[$i],0,1 )` is invalid, `is_numeric` only takes 1 argument !

Comment: if (is_numeric(substr($rowArray[$i],0,1))) did the job in the end!

Comment: @Tony, my point is t hat `,0,1` does nothing what so ever, you can remove that because its just confusing.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Sorry, looks like I removed `substr`. Fixed now. 0 and 1 are arguments of `substr`. They do matter because Tony only wants to know if the _first_ character is numeric.

Comment: Ahh makes sense now. :) +1 you count use `&& $stringArray[$i] < 10` to make sure the range is `1-9`

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to make sure that a string is a number you can use `is_numeric` like so:

```
if(is_numeric($string))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

If you want to make sure its a single digit like `7` you can use the `<` less-than operator

```
if(is_numeric($string) && $string < 10)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: This would allow strings such as "+0" or "+0.2e-1".